# When will Google stop showing a site's page after a robots.txt has been placed in it?

Tags: indexing, seo, web-crawler, robots.txt

Google is showing `www.example.com/myPage` as a search result.

I do not want this `/myPage` to be indexed by google, so a `robots.txt` was placed in the page.

How long will it take to stop being showed in google?
I know that people can still visit it if they have the URL, but my aim is just to remove it from google's search results.

My knowledge in SEO is little, and I feel the answer may vary depending on the site traffic and other SEO-related factors, but speaking in general terms, how long would this take?

Comment: robots.txt will stop crawling, not indexing. Look into remove urls in webmaster tools. Or using a noindex tag.

Comment: @user29671 That's incorrect. A robots.txt is enough to prevent indexing. However, it takes time for Google to react when a page was previously indexed. Patience is king in this case.

Comment: @AlexisWilke You are wrong. You can learn about robots.txt here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en  "You should not use robots.txt as a means to hide your web pages from Google Search results. This is because, if other pages point to your page with descriptive text, your page could still be indexed without visiting the page. "

Comment: @user29671 Well! I'll be damned! Already many of my public pages are not being indexed, if Google indexes pages just on a hunch... that page could be covered with total crap. So I'd be surprised that they would indeed so so if robots.txt prevents access and thus verification that the page is worth indexing in the first place.

Comment: Watch this video, it explains it very well  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBdEwpRQRD0  "Uncrawled URLs in search results"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crawls are based on many factors such as PageRank, links to a page, and crawling constraints such as the number of parameters in a URL. Any number of factors can affect the crawl frequency of individual sites.

The crawl process is algorithmic; computer programs determine which sites to crawl, how often, and how many pages to fetch from each site. They don't accept payment to crawl a site more frequently. For tips on maintaining a crawler-friendly website, please visit the Webmaster Guidelines.

I would suggest you to use the google webmaster tool for your SEO this will help you to see that when Google last crawled your website also there are many SEO options that will help you to index your site better.
There is also an option in Webmaster to ask Google to crawl your site again telling Google bots to re crawl your site as the content on your site has changed.

[This](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en) link might help you understand better.Also to get an overview of Webmaster setup and features visit [this](http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2191991/google-webmaster-tools-an-overview) link

Comment: So more or less your answer is "we don't know"? I think one way is to look at when the robots.txt file gets loaded again. At that point the bot has the new information and within a short time can "easily" remove certain pages from its index. However, that too is not instantaneous, but I would imagine that it's fairly quick from that point on.

Comment: robots,txt is not a tool to remove pages from the index. Adding a page to robots,txt is an instruction not to crawl. This is different from an instruction not to index. Learn about it here > https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en